# Как сделать ресурсы модуля/библиотеки приватными?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-resources, android-library

Сделать ресурсы модуля приватными для других модулей.

Пробовал, что советует [официальная документация](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html#PrivateResources) -- не работает.

Cоздал res/values/public.xml

```
<resources>
   <public name="app_name" type="string"/>
</resources>
```

Так же пробовал res/values/public.xml

```
 <resources>
    <public/>
 </resources>
```

res/values/strings.xml

```
<resources>
  <string name="app_name">app_name</string>
  <string name="app_name_2">app_name_2</string>
</resources>
```

Также пробовал без public.xml
res/values/strings.xml

```
  <resources>
    <public name="app_name" type="string"/>
   
    <string name="app_name">app_name</string>
    <string name="app_name_2">app_name_2</string>
  </resources>
```

```
<resources>
  <public />
  <string name="app_name">app_name</string>
  <string name="app_name_2">app_name_2</string>
</resources>
```

В App могу использовать `android.example.common.R.string.app_name_2`

Пожалуйста, прежде чем предлагать, проверьте, работает ли этот способ, поскольку я искал, и многие предлагают решения, которые не работают.

Comment: Как вы проверяли, что способ из официальной документации не работает? Добавьте детали вашей проверки в вопрос, возможно, проблема в том, что ресурсы не становятся приватными на самом деле. Их по-прежнему можно использовать, только их использование приведет к предупреждениям lint.

Comment: @Vadik
Спасибо, я добавил больше информации

Comment: Приватные ресурсы все равно можно использовать, об этом сказано в документации по [ссылке](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library#PrivateResources) из вопроса. Различие приватных ресурсов от публичных лишь в том, что при использовании приватных ресурсов у вас Lint выдаст предупреждение. Покажите в вопросе, какие предупреждения выдает Lint.

Comment: @Vadik Не каких предупреждений нету, но это не важно, поскольку мой вопрос как сделать ресурсы приватными, что бы не мог из app использовать эти ресурсы

Comment: Скорей всего, в Андроид нет такого механизма.

Comment: @Vadik вот [официальный Youtube канал](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Rox-HXhRfI&t=144s) где показано что приватные ресурсы, не должны попадать в список при обращение, я думаю это ошибка Android Developers

Comment: По вашей ссылке -- возможности среды разработки Android Studio. Разрабатывать приложения можно не только в среде разработки Android Studio. Можно писать код в обычном текстовом редакторе типа "Блокнот". Технически нет ограничений использовать приватные ресурсы.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю проблема со стороны Android Developers, поскольку в ихнем [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Rox-HXhRfI&t=144s) говорится как должны работать private resources, но они так не работают.

По этому я создал [запрос о проблеме](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/262588970), всех кого это коснулось можете проголосовать(верхнем правом углу) чтобы Google обратил внимание на ошибку.